# pdf2txt -A equivalent in python

Tags: python, pdfminer

I am trying to extract exploitable texts from pdfs. But some pdfs like [this one](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17vlbEy493japUpHKEjWqXcDXtmqGjPHq) seem to have a specific layout because my python script cannot keep spaces.

```
def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, password=password, caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = retstr.getvalue()

    fp.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()
    return text

print(convert_pdf_to_txt("1002459.pdf"))
```

Result :

```
- 1 -

Combininglearningandreasoning:newchallengesforknowledgegraphsFrankvanHarmelen∗∗DptofComputerScience,VrijeUniversite...
```

So I tried with `pdf2txt.py` in the command. Same result. But I found the option `-A` which gives me the expected result :

```
- 1 -

Combining learning and reasoning: new challenges for

knowledge graphs

Frank van Harmelen∗
```

Can I obtain the same result with my python script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can; just copy what `-A` does. Essentially, the troublesome PDF doesn't "print" the spaces, only the words, and the layout analysis infers that there should be spaces from the gaps. pdf2txt activates this by setting `laparams.all_texts = True`.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well You can made even In Python also
Can can cheak the code in the below given link its being made in python

https://github.com/baruchel/txt2pdf

Comment: Hello Ankit, welcome to StackOverflow! It is pretty unclear what you want to say, can you clarify what you mean and how the provided link helps answering the question?